# How did I lose 5 reputation on an answer?

Tags: support, reputation, voting

[image]

On [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66987/46231), it says I lost 5 reputation, and I'm really puzzled about what chain of events could have caused this. I don't care about the lost rep, I'm just curious to understand as I've never seen this before.

- Upvotes on answers are **+10** reputation. Removal of an upvote on an answer  would then be **-10**.
- Downvotes on questions and answers cost the author **-2** reputation; moreover, this answer has a score of **15 up / 0 down**.

The only way I could see this notification making any sense is if

- I downvoted another answer to the same question (**-1**), **and**
- Two users downvoted my answer (**-4**)

for a total of **-5**, except those would show as two separate events, and there are no downvotes on my answer.

What happened here?

Comment: Did you accidently post your answer as a question? ;)

Comment: @βετѧΛєҫαγ I might well have done considering how out of it I seem to be today :(

Comment: I propose migrating this to Puzzling SE. ;)

Answer (score 14):

A quick glance at [your reputation history](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46231/cat?tab=reputation) reveals that your answer was unaccepted (**-15**) and got an upvote (**+10)**. The sum is the **-5** you saw in the notification area.

Comment: I totally forgot it was ever accepted... now it makes sense...